# Permutations with replacement in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, recursion, combinatorics

Many a times, I've had the need to use a permutations with replacement function.

So, I've written a function to do just that:

```py
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10 ** 9)

def permutations_with_replacement(n: int, m: int, cur=None):
    if cur is None:
        cur = []

    if n == 0:
        yield cur
        return

    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        yield from permutations_with_replacement(n - 1, m, cur + [i])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("Please enter 'N': "))
    m = int(input("Please enter 'M': "))

    for i in permutations_with_replacement(n, m):
        print(*i)
```

There's a better way to do this if we used `itertools.product`, but there's no fun in that!

```py
from itertools import product

def permutations_with_replacement(n, m):
    for i in product(list(range(1, m + 1)), repeat=n):
        yield i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("Please enter 'N': "))
    m = int(input("Please enter 'M': "))

    for i in permutations_with_replacement(n, m):
        print(*i)
```

I don't like the way I've implemented `cur` in my code. Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is a very nicely written code.

Before writing about the `cur` implementation, a few notes:

- I do not think `n` and `m` should be in main. It creates shadowing in the function.
- I added type annotation to the return value of the function. Since it's a generator it should be: `Iterator[List[int]]`.

So you said you do not like the way `cur` is implemented in your code, I thought of a way to take it out of the function declaration.
I created a sub function that is recursive taken out the `cur` variable. This is how it turned out:

```py
def permutations_with_replacement(n: int, m: int) -> Iterator[List[int]]:
    cur = []

    def permutations_with_replacement_rec(n_rec: int, m_rec: int) -> Iterator[List[int]]:
        nonlocal cur

        if n_rec == 0:
            yield cur
            return

        for i in range(1, m_rec + 1):
            cur = cur + [i]
            yield from permutations_with_replacement_rec(n_rec - 1, m_rec)
            cur.pop()

    yield from permutations_with_replacement_rec(n, m)
```

Now notice that I needed to add a `pop` to the variable since now it keeps the elements after the call to the function.
Also I needed to use the `nonlocal` term so the function will know the `cur` variable.

The full code (with tests):

```py
from itertools import product
from typing import Iterator, List

from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10 ** 9)


def permutations_with_replacement(n: int, m: int) -> Iterator[List[int]]:
    cur = []

    def permutations_with_replacement_rec(n_rec: int, m_rec: int) -> Iterator[List[int]]:
        nonlocal cur

        if n_rec == 0:
            yield cur
            return

        for i in range(1, m_rec + 1):
            cur = cur + [i]
            yield from permutations_with_replacement_rec(n_rec - 1, m_rec)
            cur.pop()

    yield from permutations_with_replacement_rec(n, m)


def test_permutations_with_replacement():
    n = 3
    m = 4
    assert set(product(list(range(1, m + 1)), repeat=n)) == set(tuple(i) for i in permutations_with_replacement(n, m))


def main():
    n = int(input("Please enter 'N': "))
    m = int(input("Please enter 'M': "))

    for i in permutations_with_replacement(n, m):
        print(*i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late but I have had this idea to solve this problem iteratively. I wish to leave this here for someone who is searching for an iterative answer like me.

It is difficult to explain in English (for me), but the idea is to start updating the current permutation from the end, one index at a time. Keep updating until the initial permutation is again encountered, in which case we stop updating any more by setting `hasNext=False`.

```py
from typing import Iterator, List

def permutations_with_replacement(n: int, m: int) -> Iterator[List[int]]:
    cur = [1]*n
    hasNext = True
    while hasNext:
        yield cur
        i = n-1
        while hasNext:
            cur[i] += 1
            if cur[i] > m:
                cur[i] = 1
                i -= 1
                if i < 0:
                    hasNext = False
            else:
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("Please enter 'N': "))
    m = int(input("Please enter 'M': "))

    for i in permutations_with_replacement(n, m):
        print(*i)
```